# How to sort a list by number first in descending order and then by alphabet in ascending order

Tags: python, list, sorting, numbers, alphabet

I have a list

```
ff = [('o', 2), ('l', 1), ('e', 1), ('g', 2)]
```

and i want to sort it in such a way in which it get sorted by number in descending order and if any element have same number then it get sorted by alphabet in ascending order, like  this

```
ff = [('g', 2), ('o', 2), ('e', 1), ('l', 1)]
```

Comment: show what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with parameter `key`:

```py
ff = [('o', 2), ('l', 1), ('e', 1), ('g', 2)]

output = sorted(ff, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))

print(output) # [('g', 2), ('o', 2), ('e', 1), ('l', 1)]
```

When a tuple is given as `key`, `sorted` sorts the list lexicographically. In this case it first sorts according to the second element in descending order (`-x[1]`) and then sorts according to the first element in ascending order (`x[0]`).

Comment: Thank you, It worked. Can you pls explain me what does x: (-x[1], x[0]) means here? I am a beginner, I don't understand what it means